# Using uploaded file without move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, upload, temporary

So I want to do stuff with an csv-file that's uploaded from my computer. However it's not necessary to keep the file after I used it, so I try to just use the temporary file.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $savepath = sys_get_temp_dir() . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        doStuff($savepath);
    }
```

I get a warning: ...\Temp\php8CC0.tmp): failed to open stream: Invalid argument. Any idea what the problem could be, or is it just not recommended to work with the temporary files?

Comment: Have you read `tempnam` description?

Comment: I updated the question, I copied from an older version. Thanks for pointing out!